# How to remove specific text with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the last two span tags with CSS. My code is

```
<h1 class='av-special-heading-tag'  itemprop="headline"  >Turning </h1><div class='special-heading-border'><div class='special-heading-inner-border' ></div></div></div>
<span class="av_font_icon avia_animate_when_visible av-icon-style-  av-no-color avia-icon-pos-center " style=""><span class='av-icon-char' style='font-size:20px;line-height:20px;' aria-hidden='true' data-av_icon='' data-av_iconfont='entypo-fontello' ></span></span>
<section class="av_textblock_section"  itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork" ><div class='avia_textblock '  style='font-size:20px; '  itemprop="text" ><p style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: #641380;">Mazak Nexus 200MY</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT200M</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT10M</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT8</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Colchester lathe</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Harrison lathe</span></p>
</div></section></div>
```

So want to remove

```
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Colchester lathe</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Harrison lathe</span></p>
```

using Css 
Any help on this how to do this. I **Dont Want to do it any other way due to a problem, so can't use the visibility element.**

Comment: How about with javascript?

Comment: Can't also use Javascript/jQuery, because the theme wont let me.

Comment: You can't remove any element using CSS but you can hide element using `display: none` property.

Comment: what kind of theme does not let the developer use vanilla javascript ? :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use code bellow:**
`:nth-last-of-type(-n+2)` mean 2 last element...
`display:none;` remove them

```css
section span:nth-last-of-type(-n+2){
display:none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='av-special-heading-tag'  itemprop="headline"  >Turning </h1><div class='special-heading-border'><div class='special-heading-inner-border' ></div></div></div>
<span class="av_font_icon avia_animate_when_visible av-icon-style-  av-no-color avia-icon-pos-center " style=""><span class='av-icon-char' style='font-size:20px;line-height:20px;' aria-hidden='true' data-av_icon='' data-av_iconfont='entypo-fontello' ></span></span>
<section class="av_textblock_section"  itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork" ><div class='avia_textblock '  style='font-size:20px; '  itemprop="text" ><p style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: #641380;">Mazak Nexus 200MY</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT200M</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT10M</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT8</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Colchester lathe</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Harrison lathe</span></p>
</div></section>
```

Comment: Hi, this worked, but it also removeed other text on the same page.

Comment: be more spesific: `.av_textblock_section.avia_textblock  span:nth-last-of-type(-n+2)`

Comment: I tried adding this -                                                                                                            .av_textblock_section.avia_textblock span:nth-last-of-type(-n+2){
 display: none; 
}         still didnt work

Comment: Also I have other class names which are similar.

Comment: so add id or spesific class for this

Comment: I added a class of hide but still not working. Not sure whats wrong

Comment: <span style="color: #641380;" class="hide"> Mazak Colchester lathe</span>
         <span style="color: #641380;" class="hide"> Mazak Harrison lathe</span>

Comment: possible if your data is hard coded and not dinamic... use in css `.hide{display:none}`

Comment: Im using wordpress and the theme page builder isnt working. So just need a temproray fix. Im adding the css classes using the mysql database. I tried that code but not working. Is there a way i can change its color to white (just as a temporary fix)?

Comment: If I was to use Jquery, how will i remove it?

Comment: `$('.hide').hide()` it function that hide the element

Comment: Still cant find a fix to the problem. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2):

CSS can only affect the visual part of the DOM, therefore you will need to use JavaScript to remove the last two items.
You could `display: none;` the last two items using CSS selector, but the elements will still be in the DOM.

```css
.av_textblock_section span: nth-last-of-type(-n + 2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="av_textblock_section" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork">
  <div class='avia_textblock ' style='font-size:20px; ' itemprop="text">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
      <span style="color: #641380;">Mazak Nexus 200MY</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT200M</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT10M</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT8</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Colchester lathe</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Harrison lathe</span></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select second last element of certain type with `nth-last-of-type(2)` and the last one with `last-of-type`.

You should use `-of-type` and not `last-child` because you have some `br` elements that count as children.
If you want to use `last-child` instead, you should delete all the `br` and give `display:block` to `span` so they will stay only 1/line

I commented out the display:none and gave a `background-color` for example purposes only. You can 'uncomment' the `display:none` and the elements will get hidden. `display:none` is the most you can do with css in terms of hiding elements. You cannot remove them entirely.

As a side note, why do all the spans have the exact same inline style ? why don't you use Css for that? also the other elements have a bunch of inline styles..

```css
p span:nth-last-of-type(2),p span:last-of-type {
    background:green;
    /*display:none*/
}
```

```html
<h1 class='av-special-heading-tag' itemprop="headline">Turning </h1>
<div class='special-heading-border'>
  <div class='special-heading-inner-border'></div>
</div>
<div>
<span class="av_font_icon avia_animate_when_visible av-icon-style-  av-no-color avia-icon-pos-center " style=""><span class='av-icon-char' style='font-size:20px;line-height:20px;' aria-hidden='true' data-av_icon='' data-av_iconfont='entypo-fontello' ></span></span>
<section class="av_textblock_section" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork">
  <div class='avia_textblock ' style='font-size:20px; ' itemprop="text">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
      <span style="color: #641380;">Mazak Nexus 200MY</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT200M</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT10M</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT8</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Colchester lathe</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Harrison lathe</span></p>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

If it removes other too, just use a more specific selector like `.avia_textblock > p span:nth-last-of-type(2), .avia_textblock > p span:last-of-type { display:none}`

Comment: @java11 and? :) i don't undertstand the answer

Comment: Im working with wordpress and the theme page builder isnt working. So cant access the text. Need to use css in order to remove the text. Hope that explains it.

Comment: Yes it is but its also removing other paragraphs.

Comment: So need another fix.

Comment: @java11 it doesn't remove paragraphs, it removes the last 2 spans from a paragraph. Maybe use a more specific selector like `.avia_textblock > p span:nth-last-of-type(2), .avia_textblock > p span:last-of-type { display:none}`

Comment: The problem  have is I have other paragraphs with the same class name. So it removes other parapgraphs along with it.